# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException when pushing router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing something with React, and I'm in a problem.

Uncaught DOMException is occuring when pushing router.

It occurs when I push a new URL into router with only an event triggered from a button in modal component, otherwise(not an event triggered from a modal) the router works well.

Full procedure that I'd like to do is like below.

> 1. There's a 'delete' button on the 'content view' page.
> 2. If I click 'delete' button, 'confirm modal' appears.
> 3. If I click 'confirm' button on 'confirm modal', the content is deleted and move to 'list view'.

My Exception occurs right after deleting content.

Belows are my source codes.

'delete' button:

```
<button key={keygen._()} className="btn btn-info btn-xs" style={{ marginRight: '4px' }} onClick={this._handleOnClickDel}>
        <i className="fa fa-eraser"></i> DELETE
</button>
```

'_handleOnClickDel' function:

```
_handleOnClickDel(e) {
  e.target.disabled = true;
  this.setState({
    showMessageModal: true, // this shows 'confirm modal'
  });
}
```

'confirm modal' component:

```
<MessageModal
  message="Are you sure?"
  show={this.state.showMessageModal}
  cancelBtnTxt="CANCEL"
  confirmBtnTxt="CONFIRM"
  onConfirmClick={this._handleOnConfirmDelClick}
  close={this._hideMessageModal}
/>
```

'_handleOnConfirmDelClick' function:

```
_handleOnConfirmDelClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  deleteById(this.props.params.boardId) // this deletes the content from DB
  .then(() => {
    this.context.router.push(`/community/${this.state.type}`);
  });
}
```

The full exception message on browser console is like below.

> Portal.js?8f33:75 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
>       at Constructor._unmountOverlayTarget (eval at  (http://localhost:8000/dist/bundle.js:4284:2), :75:33)
>       at Constructor.componentWillUnmount (eval at  (http://localhost:8000/dist/bundle.js:4284:2), :62:10)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.unmountComponent (eval at  (http://localhost:8000/dist/bundle.js:3138:2), :395:14)
>       at Object.unmountComponent (eval at  (http://localhost:8000/dist/bundle.js:2790:2), :80:22)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.unmountComponent (eval at  (http://localhost:8000/dist/bundle.js:3138:2), :405:23)
>       at Object.unmountComponent (eval at  (http://localhost:8000/dist/bundle.js:2790:2), :80:22)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.unmountComponent (eval at  (http://localhost:8000/dist/bundle.js:3138:2), :405:23)
>       at Object.unmountComponent (eval at  (http://localhost:8000/dist/bundle.js:2790:2), :80:22)
>       at Object.unmountChildren (eval at  (http://localhost:8000/dist/bundle.js:3126:2), :118:25)
>       at ReactDOMComponent.unmountChildren (eval at  (http://localhost:8000/dist/bundle.js:3114:2), :346:28)

Answer will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this` explicitly on invoking `_handleOnConfirmDelClick` method from modal, so change it from:

```
onConfirmClick={this._handleOnConfirmDelClick}
```

to:

```
onConfirmClick={this._handleOnConfirmDelClick.bind(this)}
```

and the method itself to be:

```
_handleOnConfirmDelClick(e, this) {
  var self = this;
  e.preventDefault();
  deleteById(this.props.params.boardId) // this deletes the content from DB
  .then(() => {
    self.context.router.push(`/community/${this.state.type}`);
  });
}
```

To read more about binding javascript `this` in ReactJS, see [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/).

Comment: Thanks but surely I did '.bind(this)' of all function in constructor function of the view. Is there any reason to bind at property declaration?

Comment: If you did so in the constructor, so no need for it, but still in the deletion callback, `this` refers to the on-the-fly function not the React class. That's why you need to do it explicitly.

Comment: If I put this into an argument of '_handleOnConfirmDelClick', a build error occurs on the line. Do you mean the 'context' object on my code is owned by not React class?

Comment: I found the 'this' of 'this.context.router.push' refers to the view component by printing console. It's not a matter of reference but another thing.